# XSLT 1.0 How to keep namespace declaration at root

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm working with [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) 1.0 (*as processing software doesn't support 2.0*) and I've been searching for a way to make all the namespace definitions on my output xml to be put at the root node. Anyone has any idea how to do this?

Here is a small example of what I'm doing, what I get, and what I'm after:

**Input XML:**

```
<document Version="1.4">
<Series>A</Series>
<Folio>321</Folio>
<Date>2017-05-05T01:00:00</Date>
<Complement>
    <Other>
        <Version>4.2</Version>
        <Type>K</Type>
        <PaymentDate>2016-12-13</PaymentDate> 
    </Other>
</Complement>
</document>
```

**My XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet extension-element-prefixes="xsi" version="1.0" xmlns:A="http://example.com/A" xmlns:C="http://example.com/C" xmlns:local="urn:local" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:B="http://example.com/B" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/A http://example.com/A/A.xsd">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="A:Document">
        <xsl:attribute name="Version">
            <xsl:text>9.1</xsl:text>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="/document/Series/node() and /document/Series != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="Series">
                <xsl:value-of select="/document/Series"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:if test="/document/Folio/node() and /document/Folio != ''">
            <xsl:attribute name="Folio">
                <xsl:value-of select="/document/Folio"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:attribute name="Date">
            <xsl:value-of select="/document/Date"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:if test="/document/Complement/Other/node() or /document/Complement/Another/node()">
            <xsl:element name="A:Complement">
                <xsl:if test="/document/Complement/Other/node()">
                    <xsl:element name="B:Payment">
                        <xsl:call-template name="B:Payment">
                            <xsl:with-param name="Node" select="/document/Complement/Other"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!--- COMPLEMENT-->
<xsl:template name="B:Payment">
    <xsl:param name="Node"/>
    <xsl:attribute name="Version">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Node/Version"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Type">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Node/Type"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="PaymentDate">
        <xsl:value-of select="$Node/PaymentDate"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**The output:**

```
<A:Document Version="9.1" Series="A" Folio="321" Date="2017-05-05T01:00:00" xmlns:A="http://example.com/A">
    <A:Complement>
        <B:Payment Version="4.2" Type="K" PaymentDate="2016-12-13" xmlns:B="http://example.com/B" />
    </A:Complement>
</A:Document>
```

**What I need:**

```
<A:Document Version="9.1" Series="A" Folio="321" Date="2017-05-05T01:00:00" xmlns:A="http://example.com/A" xmlns:B="http://example.com/B">
    <A:Complement>
        <B:Payment Version="4.2" Type="K" PaymentDate="2016-12-13" />
    </A:Complement>
</A:Document>
```

As you can see, what I need is that both namespace declarations be kept at the root node (as requested by the software that will process this XML)

**Some additional information:**

- I can only use XSLT 1.0 as mentioned earlier, since that is the only one the current tool I can use supports (there are plans to change this, but won't be done in the near future)
- This has to be done entirely using XSLT
- As you can probably infer from the sample, the "Other" node is optional, so it can be present (in which case the namespace on the output is required) or not (in which case, the namespace declaration should not be present)
- There are more of this "optional" nodes, each one with it's own namespace
- It doesn't have to be just 1 XSLT though, if this can be fixed by passing the output through a new XSLT, that would work just fine

I'm an XSLT newbie, so any help with this (or directions to some literature where I can learn how to do this) would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks for the edits =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use literal result element with i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <A:Document>
```

then you only need `exclude-result-prefixes="xsi C local msxsl"` with i.e.

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsi C local msxsl" version="1.0" xmlns:A="http://example.com/A" xmlns:C="http://example.com/C" xmlns:local="urn:local" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:B="http://example.com/B" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/A http://example.com/A/A.xsd">
```

and that way the XSLT processor will output

```
<A:Document xmlns:A="http://example.com/A" xmlns:B="http://example.com/B" Version="9.1" Series="A" Folio="321" Date="2017-05-05T01:00:00">
```

Only use `xsl:element` if you need to compute the element name or namespace at run-time.

As for resources and tutorials, one book available online for free now us https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/.

Comment: Oh, that completely solved it. Thanks for the help and for the link =D

Answer (score 1):

If you know statically (i.e. at the time you write the stylesheet) what the outermost element in the result tree should be, and what namespaces it should have, then you can achieve this trivially using a literal result element:

```
<A:Element xmlns:A="some.uri" xmlns:B="some.other.uri">
  ...
</A:Element>
```

If you want to copy the element name and namespaces from the source document, then you can use `<xsl:copy>`.

To copy all the namespaces from the source document, wherever they appear, into the new root element, you could construct the root element using

```
<xsl:element name="{$name}">
   <xsl:copy-of select="//namespace::*"/>
   ...
</xsl:element>
```

In other cases it's more difficult. In XSLT 1.0 the only way you can create namespace nodes dynamically in the most general case is by constructing a dummy element in the relevant namespace and then using `<xsl:copy-of select="exslt:node-set($dummy)//namespace::x"/>` to copy its namespace nodes. But this is very rarely necessary.